# Scrolling effect as per in Bootswatch template

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to do an element fixed to the top when user scrolls beyond the element in height as per "#subnav" div in this page http://bootswatch.com/simplex/

Looking around google, I managed to form the following function and code.

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    if(docViewTop >= elemBottom){
    return true;
    }else{
    return false;
    }
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(!$("#search_menu").hasClass("subnav-fixed")){
        if(!isScrolledIntoView($("#search_menu"))){
            $("#search_menu").addClass("subnav-fixed");
        }       
    }else{

        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

        $("#window_top").html(docViewTop);
        $("#window_bottom").html(docViewBottom);
        $("#height").html(element_frm_top);

        if(docViewTop < element_frm_top < docViewBottom){
            $("#search_menu").removeClass("subnav-fixed");
        }
    }
});
```

Using this. I was able to add the class subnav-fixed and get the div position fixed to the top. But I'm not able to get it to return to its original position after scrolling back up. Wonder where's gone wrong or if someone else have a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(!$("#search_menu").hasClass("subnav-fixed")){
        if(!isScrolledIntoView($("#search_menu"))){
            $("#search_menu").addClass("subnav-fixed");
        }       
    }else{
        if(isScrolledIntoView($("#search_menu"))){
            $("#search_menu").removeClass("subnav-fixed");
        }
    }
});
```

did not tested.

Also consider changing `if(docViewTop >= elemBottom)` to `if(docViewTop >= elemTop)`

**EDIT**

It depends where do you place your #search_menu. Assuming it will be top: 40px it should be:

http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/yDPeZ/

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top - 40;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    if (docViewTop >= elemTop) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var $body = $('body'),
        $menu = $("#search_menu");
    if (!$menu.hasClass("subnav-fixed")) {
        if (isScrolledIntoView($menu)) {
            $menu.addClass("subnav-fixed");
        }
    } else {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 40) {
            $menu.removeClass("subnav-fixed");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Lovely;) Worked Just the way i wanted it to. Thanks